# How do I achieve a redelivery delay in azure service bus with amqp using rhea

Tags: amqp, azureservicebus, rhea

I'm using rhea in a nodejs application to send messages around over Azure Service Bus using AMQP. My problem is as follows:

Sometimes a message processing attempt can fail because of something that is out of our hands. For instance, a call to some API could fail because a service is down. At that point we unlock the message so it can be picked up at a later time or by another instance. After a certain amount of retries (when delivery-count has hit a certain max) it just ends up in DLQ.

What I want to achieve is that between each delivery attempt there is an increasing pause so the X amount of retries don't just occur in rapid succession until the max is hit. This way I can give whatever is causing the failure some time to come back up if it's just a matter of waiting for some service to become available again. If that doesn't work the message can go to DLQ anyway.

Is there some setting in azure service bus that will achieve this or will I have to program this into my own application?

Answer (score 0):

if you explicitly want to delay processing you can en-queue a new message with ScheduledEnqueueTime set of later delivery (using the message.Clone() function can help in creating the cloned message). You also have the ability to call message.Defer() and will not deliver this message again until you call Receive(Sequenceid) for that specific message at a later time .